# Refresh Konva Stage

Tags: html, canvas, konvajs

I am using Konva JS, which will have lots of elements added on stage which will be added on different user actions. Sometime I need to destroy this elements on certain user action. My code is working fine, it's destroying the required element, but not from UI. On next user action it will automatically removed from screen/UI.  My elements(a rect and a img)are wrapped inside a group , and I am trying to destroy this group.

So I think my issue is : Stage/Layer is not getting refreshed on "Destroy".

Thanks in advance

Comment: My code to destroy groups is :  mygroup.destroyChildren();           mygroup.destroy();

Comment: You have to draw the layer group or stage after destroy to reflect the changed DOM in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Konva JS** over **ReactJS framework**, make sure to retrieve the right list of object before rendering. To delete a node, **delete it from state by resetting a new value** without the node to delete, so that **the view will be automatically rerendered**.